# calculate available weeks in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a method who calculates available weeks based on current date and already used dates.

I've come up with different solutions but all of them seems way to "ugly" for Ruby. I know there is a better way to do it.

Requirements:

Method takes 3 arguments

```
start  - Date, to start calculation from

amount - Integer, How many weeks do we want?

used_weeks - Array of already used weeknumbers (optional) Default: nil
```

Let's say we pass the method this:

```
calculate_available_weeks (Date.current, 5, [1,3,7])
```

(Let's say Date.current returns *Sun, 01 Jan 2012* for simplicity)

Then the method should return Dates for following weeks: 2,4,5,6,8

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def calculate_week_dates(start, amount, excluded_weeks = nil)
  weeks = []

  last_checked = start
  until weeks.length == amount do
    unless excluded_weeks && excluded_weeks.include?(last_checked.cweek)
      weeks << last_checked
    end
    last_checked = last_checked.next_week
  end

  weeks
end
```

Comment: Your example output disagrees with your code example. You seem to specify cweek numbers in the output, but your code accepts cweeks in the exclusion but produces dates rather than week numbers in its result.  What do you want to get when current plus amount weeks wraps into next year?

Answer (score 1):

This is why I love ruby.

```
def calculate(starting_week, amount, excluded_weeks = [])
  ((starting_week..52).to_a - excluded_weeks).first(amount)
end

puts calculate( 1, 5, [1,3,7]).inspect # => [2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
puts calculate( 5, 5, [1,3,7]).inspect # => [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
puts calculate(10, 5, [1,3,7]).inspect # => [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: What happens when start_week + amount + excluded_weeks.size wrap into the following year?

Comment: @iblue: Yes it is, Thats why I'm passing start as a Date, nice snippet fro other calculations though!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it chaining functional enumerators:

```
def calculate_week_dates(start, amount, excluded_weeks = [])
  (0 ... amount + excluded_weeks.size).
  inject( [start] ) {|a,wk| a << a.last.next_week }.
  reject {|wk| excluded_weeks.include? wk.cweek }.
  first(amount)
end
```

But I'm of mixed feeling whether this is clearer or prettier than an accumulation loop.  In either case, you're better off asserting that excluded_weeks is an empty array instead of nil to avoid the later nil guards when you want to use it.